# Why Not Always Use EnableCrossPartitionQuery

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

If my cosmos DB has multiple partitions is there any reason to NOT set `EnableCrossPartitionQuery` to **true**?

I know it is necessary if running a query that could hit multiple partitions. But what if the query uses a valid partition key and definitely will only hit one partition, is there any performance loss or increased cost because I set that flag to true?

Comment: Isn't that something that you can simply test? You can set the query metrics to true and get your answer by looking at the stats. Did you try that?

Comment: You are right, it is, but it's quicker if someone 'just knows' the answer. If no-one knows off the top of their head then I'll test it for sure :)

Comment: @wallismark Hi,does my answer helps you?

Comment: @JayGong yes thank you! (sorry for the delay :) )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But what if the query uses a valid partition key and definitely will
>   only hit one partition, is there any performance loss or increased
>   cost because I set that flag to true?

Per my knowledge, you need set the partition key for partitioned collection and the cost will not change even if you still set the `EnableCrossPartitionQuery` as true.Because the request only scans the specific partition you already set. I did a sample test and try to verify it.

```
    FeedOptions feedOptions = new FeedOptions();
    PartitionKey partitionKey = new PartitionKey("A");
    feedOptions.setPartitionKey(partitionKey);
    feedOptions.setEnableCrossPartitionQuery(true);

    FeedResponse<Document> queryResults = client.queryDocuments(
            "/dbs/db/colls/part",
            "SELECT * FROM c",
            feedOptions);

    System.out.println("Running SQL query...");
    for (Document document : queryResults.getQueryIterable()) {
        System.out.println(String.format("\tRead %s", document));
    }

    System.out.println(queryResults.getRequestCharge());
```

[image]

I think maybe you don't have to struggle with this problem. `EnableCrossPartitionQuery` option only need to be used if the query for partitioned collection is not scoped to single partition key value. If you know the specific partition key,then no need to set `EnableCrossPartitionQuery`.

Comment: Is this option still valid? I cannot it on this page: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql/how-to-query-container